# Passing the Object Type dynamically

Tags: c#

I have this code that has the [Ent] inside the using

```
 public static void Retion()
        {

            using (Ent entitiesContext = new Ent())
                {...}
         {
```

I need to pass the [Ent] dynamically, like this:

```
 public static void Retion(Type ds)
            {

                using (ds entitiesContext = new ds())
                    {...}
             {
```

This of course does not work. How to I change this so that I can pass it dynamically?

Comment: The type will most probably be in the assembly. If you are loading it dynamically then you have to design that type to implement an interface...its similar to how remoting would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps via generics:

```
public static void Retion<T>() where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    using (T entitiesContext = new T())
    {...}
```

then `Retion<Ent>()`

Note that to do anything *useful* with `entitiesContext`, you'll probably also need some base--class constraint, i.e.

```
public static void Retion<T>() where T : DataContext, new()
{
    using (T entitiesContext = new T())
    {...}
```

Of course, that then isn't hugely different to:

```
public static void Retion(Type type)
{
    using (DataContext entitiesContext = 
        (DataContext)Activator.CreateInstance(type))
    {...}
```

Comment: I am accepting this because of the base-class constraint. Just wondering if I need to use the IDisposable in addition to the DataContext base-class constraint?

Comment: @user that depends on whether the base-class implements it

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
   public static void Retion<T>() where T : IDisposable, new()
   { 

            using (T entitiesContext = new T()) 
                {...} 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void Retion< T >(T ds) where T :new()
            {

```
            using (T entitiesContext = new T())
                {...}
         {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call constructor from type by reflection